# C# MailMessage send and display formatted tags

Tags: c#, html

I have a simple question, but maybe not for a simple answer :

How is it possible with a MailMessage object to send a mail with a body
that contains (as string), for exemple, "`<b><b></b>`" (without any space) ?

In fact, I need to (at the end) open a mail with as body as below :

**< b>** (without space)

As we can see, we have a three characters '<', 'b', '>' in bold.
Indeed, the goal isn't to format an unformatted tag, but just to display a tag unformatted (so not a tag) in a formatted body !

I have as exemple the string `<b>This is a tag</b> : <b>`,
and I simply want to display : "**This is a tag** : `<b>`".

I hope that the question is clear :-)
Thanks for your knowledge and sharing !

Comment: Do you mean sending HTML as body of your mail?

Comment: mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the actual `<` and `>` characters, replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

For example the string `<b>This is a tag</b> : &lt;b&gt;` would be rendered in HTML like this:

> **This is a tag** : <b>

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed :-)